# Tensorboard Embedding training faster r-cnn inception v2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, embedding, projector

I'm using faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config to train a model with my own images.

Using that config, in tensorboard I see the the Projector tab with the PCA and T_SNE visualizations (1024 points and 36 dimension)

How can I create the tsv and sprite to visualize my labels and images there?

I don't know how to extract the features from the Faster r-cnn inception V2 so I could create the tsv and sprite for those 1024 points, or whatever is needed for label and image visualization.

Is there any code, or tutorial for doing this?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, let me know if you have found something useful. Thank you.

Comment: Haven't found anything unfortunately.